# Call different functions depending on a parameter

Tags: swift, function

I'm rewriting some code, and trying to make a function less nested. The function takes an enum as an argument and does a `switch` on it. This is okay, but it adds two levels of indentation.

What I'd like to do, is something like this:

```
func getTrips<T : TripStatus.Confirmed> (status:T) {
    //Do one thing
}

func getTrips<T : TripStatus.Unconfirmed> (status:T) {
    //Do another thing
}
```

The enum is defined like:

```
enum TripStatus:String {
    case Confirmed = "Confirmed", Unconfirmed = "Unconfirmed", Tracking = "Tracking", Empty = "Empty"
}
```

The goal is that I can just call `getTrips(status)` and Swift picks the correct function based on the enum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a computed property to your `TripStatus` returning the function you want to execute based on the status and then call that. For example (in the example I return an optional function):

```
enum TripStatus: String {
    case Confirmed = "Confirmed", Unconfirmed = "Unconfirmed", Tracking = "Tracking", Empty = "Empty"

    var getTrips : (() -> ())? {
        switch self {
            case .Confirmed:    return self.getConfirmedTrips
            case .Unconfirmed:  return self.getUnconfirmedTrips
            default:            return nil
        }
    }

    func getConfirmedTrips() { print("getConfirmedTrips") }
    func getUnconfirmedTrips() { print("getConfirmedTrips") }
}

let status = TripStatus.Confirmed

status.getTrips?() // prints getConfirmedTrips
```

Answer (score 2):

`TripStatus.Confirmed` is a value, not a type. This is why in Swift 3 the proper style will be `TripStatus.confirmed`. Swift can only specialize functions on types, not values. So can't do what you're describing any more than you can define a function `func sqrt(1) { return 1 }` (that kind of function definition is common in several languages; just not Swift).

So eventually your `switch` statement (or equivalent `if`) has to exist. You can rearrange the code by putting the Confirmed logic into its own function and calling that from the `switch`, and that will let you avoid excessive indenting, but you can't avoid the runtime conditional. That's just Swift.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification. I will accept the other answer though, as I went with that implementation.